# Galois connexion restricted to an equivalence of categories.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, galois-theory

Let $ \mathcal{K} / \mathcal{K}_0 $ be a Galois field extension, with Galois group $ \mathcal{G} = \mathrm{Gal} (\mathcal{K} / \mathcal{K}_0 ) $.

Let's put :

$ F \ : \ L \in (\mathcal{P} (\mathcal{K}) \subset) \ \ \rightarrow \ \ F (L) = \{ \ g \in \mathcal{G} \ | \ x \in L \ \Rightarrow \ g(x) = x \ \} \in (\mathcal{P} (\mathcal{G}) \supset) $.
$ G \ : \ H \in (\mathcal{P} (\mathcal{G}) \supset) \ \ \rightarrow \ \ G (H) = \{ \ x \in \mathcal{K} \ | \ g \in H \ \Rightarrow \ g(x) = x \ \} \in (\mathcal{P} (\mathcal{K}) \subset) $

Then, $ F $ and $ G $ form a Galois correspondance, ie:

$ \forall L \subset \mathcal{K} \ \forall H \subset \mathcal{G} $ : $ L \subset G(H) \ \ \Longleftrightarrow \ \ F (L) \supset H $

According to the following link: [How is the notion of adjunction of two functors usefull?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249883/how-is-the-notion-of-adjunction-of-two-functors-usefull) , $ F $ and $ G $ are restricted to an equivalence categories : $ \mathrm{Fix} (\eta) = \mathrm{Fix} (\epsilon) $.

My question is :
In our case about Galois correspondence relating to Galois theory, what is $ \mathrm{Fix} (\eta) $ and what $ \mathrm{Fix} (\epsilon) $ ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What is the main theorem of Galois theory ?

Comment: Tthe main theorem of Galois theory says that there is a bijection between the set of sub-groups of $ \mathcal{G} $ and the set of sub-fields between $ \mathcal{K}_0 $ and $ \mathcal{K} $, no ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: That is exactly the equivalence you seek

Comment: Thank you. :-) If it is exactly the equivalence i seek, why, in general, is not an equivalence of cetegories but only an adjunction ? what is exactly the difference between the restriction case ( i.e : the equivalence of categories ) and the general adjunction ? :-)

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is not an equivalence of category ? Surely you know plenty of adjunction that are not equivalence of categories...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remark that $F(L)$ is always a subgroup of $\mathcal G$ for any $L \subseteq \mathcal K$ and $G(H)$ is always a subfield of $\mathcal K$ for any $H \subseteq \mathcal G$.

So, in particular,
$$\mathrm{Fix}(\eta) = \{L \subseteq \mathcal K : L=GF(L)\} \subseteq \{\text{field extensions}\ \mathcal K_0 \hookrightarrow L \hookrightarrow \mathcal K\} \hskip 40pt (1)\\
\mathrm{Fix}(\epsilon) = \{H \subseteq \mathcal G : H=FG(H)\} \subseteq \{\text{subgroups}\ H<\mathcal G\}\hskip 82pt (2)$$

Now, Galois theory tells you that (1) and (2) are actually equalities.