# Surjection between two categories and adjunction.

Tags: category-theory, galois-theory

According to the two following links : [How is the notion of adjunction of two functors usefull?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249883/how-is-the-notion-of-adjunction-of-two-functors-usefull)
and, [Galois connexion restricted to an equivalence of categories.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1458592/galois-connexion-restricted-to-an-equivalence-of-categories)
I would like to know, under which conditions we can express that there is only : $ F \circ G = \mathrm{id} $ but not
$ G \circ F = \mathrm{id} $ ?

How can we express that phenomena, using only the notion of adjunction or the equivalence of categories :
$ \mathrm{Fix} ( \eta ) \simeq \mathrm{Fix} ( \epsilon ) $ ?

In other words, $ F \circ G = \mathrm{id} $ means that there is only a surjection : $ \mathrm{Hom} ( F(X) , Y) \to \mathrm{Hom} ( X , G(Y) ) $ or, there is only a surjection : $ \mathrm{Fix} ( \eta ) \to \mathrm{Fix}( \epsilon ) $ or what exactly ?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It is extremely rare, in practice, to have $F \circ G$ *equal* to the identity. It is much more common to have $F \circ G$ to be *naturally isomorphic* to the identity. The symbols "$=$" and "$\cong$" (or however you want to denote isomorphism) are not interchangeable.

Comment: Yes, sorry. $ F \circ G \simeq \mathrm{id} $.  :-)