# Analogy between the notion of adjunction of two functors, and the notion of factorization of a morphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I would like to know if there exists any analogy or any link between the two notions of morphism factorization and the adjunction
of two functors.

According to the following link : [How is the notion of adjunction of two functors usefull?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249883/how-is-the-notion-of-adjunction-of-two-functors-usefull)
The adjunction : $ ( F , G , \eta , \epsilon ) : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D} $ induces an équivalence of categories ( i.e : a bijection ) : 
$ \mathrm{Fix} ( \eta ) \simeq \mathrm{Fix} ( \epsilon ) $.

According to the following link : http://jl.baril.u-bourgogne.fr/treillis.pdf page : $ 8 $, 
The morphism of two sets : $ f : X \to Y $ induces a bijection : $ \overline{f} : X / \sim_X \ \longrightarrow \ Y / \sim_Y $

In other words, i would like to factorize $ f : X \to Y $ like above, using the notion of the adjunction of two funtors to determine.

Conversely, i would like to find, from the factorization property of a morphism : $ f : X \to Y $, a two adjoint functors each others $ F $ and $ G $, such that :
$ \mathrm{Fix} ( \eta ) \simeq \mathrm{Fix} ( \epsilon ) $ to be a traslation of the factorization bijection : $ X / \sim_X \ \simeq \ Y / \sim_Y $.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What is Fix(...) ?

Comment: $ \mathrm{Fix} ( \eta ) = \{ X \in \mathrm{Obj} ( \mathcal{C} ) \ | \ \eta (X) : X \to F(G(X)) \ \text{ is an isomorphism  } \ \} $

Comment: What exactly are $\sim_X$ and $\sim_Y$ if $f$ is given?

Comment: $ \sim_X $ ( resp. $ \sim_Y $ ) is any equivalence relation over $ X $ ( resp. $ Y $ ).  :-)